# Printing a filled box with Python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, box

my beginner brain is again unable to get this to work. I need to print a solid box where the user determines height, width, and what character is used in the print. How should I define the range in the for loop? Clearly not as I have done here:

```
def print_box(w, h, m):
    """print filled box"""
    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(h):
            print(m, end = "")
        
def main():
    w = input("Enter the width of a frame: ", )
    h = input("Enter the height of a frame: ", )
    m = input("Enter a print mark: ")

    print()
    print_box(w, h, m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your loops backwards. The outer loop should be height, inner loop should be width.

You also need to print a newline after each line.

You don't really need the inner loop, since you can multiply a string to repeat it.

```
def print_box(w, h, m):
    """print filled box"""
    for _ in range(h):
        print(m * w)
```